Age of consent in government laws vs in islamic laws
is it permissible for a state to enforce the age of 18 as the age of consent if the age of consent in Islam is the age of puberty or is that against Islam? also is it permissible for me to break the law and get married before the age of 18 if i have reached puberty?

Regarding to it is permissible for state like it's the "state laws" the "man-made laws" which we can't do anything in it but just to ignore them if the laws are inhumane like adultery, prostitution, gambling even before 18 and stuff is totally lawful in their laws but if a person is totally conscious in their physical and mental state can't marry off even if their family is totally stable these kinds of things itself shows how immoral and subjective the laws are so there is not much to think about it even and for marrying before 18 yes it is permissible in islam the conditions are if it's male then he should have proper monetary flow in his pockets to handle the things and before marriage he should have to look upon himself that his parents(if alive) have to look upon them too with proper due and respect because it is a big fard and he should have to mentally and physically matured and know everything regarding to marital issues or post-marital matters like how to handle the things and rest everything is ok and ask a scholar to about it, rest Allah knows best and hope it helped you akhi.
